# Hibernate Lazy loading of Parent entity in Child entity (@ManyToOne)

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading, many-to-one

I have 2 entities with Parent Child relationship in Hibernate (4.2).

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "WORLDZONE")
public class Worldzone implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Column
    private BigDecimal id;

    @Column
    private Integer version;

    @Column
    private String worldZoneCd;
    // setters & getters
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "COUNTRY")
public class Country implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Column
    private BigDecimal id;

    @Column
    private Integer version;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "WORLDZONE_ID")
    private Worldzone worldzone;
    // setters & getters
}
```

In Spring MVC (4.1.3), I use Jackson ObjectMapper to convert my service responses to JSON.

While converting the response of Child entity, Jackson fails with error - `no session`. Basically, at the time of converting the object into JSON, it does not find Hibernate session to lazily load the data and convert it to JSON.

My question is what configuration is required to allow Jackson to have a session available for lazy loading of Parent entity.

I have tried below options with no luck -

Option 1:

Added a custom ObjectMapper using info from this [link](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate/tree/master/hibernate4)

```java
public class HibernateAwareObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {
    public HibernateAwareObjectMapper() {
        Hibernate4Module hm = new Hibernate4Module();
        hm.configure(Hibernate4Module.Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING, true);
        registerModule(hm);  
    }
}
```

After configuring the message-converter in servlet-context.xml, the error stopped. But data is coming as null for Parent.

Option 2:

Configured `OpenSessionInViewFilter` in web.xml. But at the time of object conversion, session is not available to Jackson.

Any pointers would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

If you are serving up your entity through a rest controller or mvc controller. Mark that as @Transactional, that will leave the session open in hibernate and allow lazy loaded properties to be evaluated when Jackson steps on them. I would personally separate your entities from your DTOs and use something like Dozer to do the mapping between the 2. That way you can encapsulate the fetching from a repository and projecting to a DTO logic in a service which can be transactional instead.